# Could it withstand it?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Could the crystal form from the Female Titan or the Warhammer withstand

> the rumbling? - Like would it get crushed or just pushed into the ground?

Answer (score 1):

The only ways to destroy the crystal hardening that has been shown in the manga are being destroyed by another hardening like jaw titan, or founding titan scream

> just like when Eren undid all the hardening in chapter 122

so I don't think they get destroyed by:

> titan rumbling

they just get pushed into the ground